# How to access the menu bar in word programatically using c#

Tags: c#

We have created a VSTO ribbon and installed under my machine. Whenever I open a word document I can see my ribbon available in the menu bar. Now I have created a console application and open the existing document but I am unable to access the VSTO menu item dynamically. Can anyone help me how to approach to access the menu items dynamically in c#

I have created a console application and opening the existing document using word interop but I am unable to find the menu lists. I have tried in VSTO but none of those worked out

Now I would like to access the VM form designer dynamically and click on the save button using c#:

[image: image of ribbon]

I have this code:

```cs
Application wordApp = new Application
{
    Visible = false
};

DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\WordPlugin\\AutomationApp\\AutomationApp\\Content\\Templates");

string tempFile = "D:\\WordPlugin\\AutomationApp\\AutomationApp\\Content\\Templates";
FileInfo[] fileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
object missing = Missing.Value;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = false;

foreach (FileInfo info in fileInfo)
{
    object filename = info.FullName;

    Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                          ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    doc.Activate();

    //if (!info.Name.Contains(".docx"))
    string newFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", tempFile, info.Name.Replace(".doc", ".docx"));

    doc.SaveAs2(newFileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument,
         CompatibilityMode: WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2013);
    var documentAddIn = doc.Application.ActiveDocument;

}
```

I am hoping to find out how I can access the menu bar items - Home, Insert, Design and my VSTO menu item.

Comment: I don't think you can access the buttons on the ribbon except by calling [ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Office.CommandBars.ExecuteMso) - but why are you trying to do that anyway, rather than write interop code which does what you need? You can [expose an object from your add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions?view=vs-2019) which your interop code can call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have created VSTO and installed for word to convert the document into JSON. Now we have many forms to convert into JSON. Doing one by one will consume more time so we planned to go for automation.  I have written the code in interop and calling the VSTO add in but due to some reason we kept this on hold and trying for automation. So looking for the approach which can click on the menu button and convert the template into JSON

Comment: When you created the VSTO you would have assigned identifiers for the buttons (if it's anything like the old add-in model) so you might be able to invoke those from the interop API.

Comment: We have used 2013 add-in model. Can i able to invoke from interop API. If posible Can you please guide me how to invoke the button from interop?

Comment: As far as I know it's just `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso(controlId)`. You can get the built-in identifiers from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

Comment: Thanks for the help. unfortunately Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso(controlId) is not helping me out